# How to run JUnit from command line with vm arguments?

Tags: java, junit

Is there any way to run JUnit test cases with program arguments, VM arguments and working directory?

I've tried with `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`, but I can't find the way to pass these parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass system parameters with the `-Dproperty=value`

Program arguments are just passed at the end of the java command line. However, they will be passed to Junit's `main` method. so you cannot use them in your test class. If you want to use some parameter in your test class, set a system parameter and retrieve it with `System.getProperty(String)` in your code.

So the command line would look like this (you probably need to set other options like classpath):

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dmy.param=foo org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.package.MyTest
```

For the working directory I would change to the desired directory with `cd` before invoking JUnit.